# Problems running PhoneGap App on my Android mobile

Tags: android, cordova, android-manifest, launching-application

I'm trying to test for first time my App on my mobile phone, I already did all the usb driver installation, allow non-market apps to install stuff... and now when I launch I get this error on Eclipse LogCat, I don't know what to do anymore, it's a PhoneGap app by the way:

```
01-22 12:40:08.534: W/asset(15063): Asset path /data/app/com.example.appprueba-1.apk is                                                                              neither a directory nor file (type=1).
01-22 12:40:08.542: W/asset(15063): Asset path /data/app/com.example.appprueba-1.apk is neither a directory nor file (type=1).
01-22 12:40:08.542: D/AndroidRuntime(15063): Shutting down VM
01-22 12:40:08.542: W/dalvikvm(15063): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410aa930)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.appprueba/com.example.appprueba.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.appprueba.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.appprueba-1.apk
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.appprueba.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.appprueba-1.apk
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
01-22 12:40:08.550: E/AndroidRuntime(15063):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have not put everything on its place, review Tutorials and have set everything as it says..

Check docs and implementation on phonegap website as well as cardova website.